# How to set and recieve cookie when backend (nestjs) is hosted and frontend (react) is not hosted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, nestjs, cross-domain

Current Scenario:

In nestjs I have used the following function to enable CORS:

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:4000'],
    credentials: true,
});
```

and the following function to set cookie:

```
response.cookie('jwt', tokens.refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
```

In react I am using the following axios request:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/refresh', {withCredentials: true})
```

This works when both the applications are in the same system (running as localhost on different posts) or if both applications are hosted in which case I can add the domain in origin inside app.enableCors function.

Requirement:
If the nest application is hosted (let's say as 'apis.abc.com') and the react application is not hosted and is running on a pc (localhost), how should I allow the hosted nest application to set and receive cookies in this case?

Adding '*' in enableCors origin property would not work as "{withCredentials: true}" needs to be used in react (to allow sending cookies to the server) and it restricts using '*'.

Use Case: A front end developer needs to develop application in his own pc (be sending requests to the hosted backend application).